# When will Nvidia CUDA toolkit be updated to version 11?

Tags: apt, nvidia, cuda, tensorflow

For latest TensorFlow version 2.4 the Nvidia CUDA toolkit is required in version 11. However, the official Ubuntu repo does only include CUDA toolkit version 10:

```
$ sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
nvidia-cuda-toolkit is already the newest version (10.1.243-3).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I know one can install CUDA (toolkit) directly from Nvidia `deb` packages, but I would rather stick to the official Ubuntu repo, if possible. Is there any estimation when the latest CUDA toolkit version 11 will be released in the official Ubuntu repo?

Comment: A simple `rmadison nvidia-cuda-toolkit` tells me 11.0.3-1ubuntu1 was available in Ubuntu *groovy*, and 11.1.1-3....   https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=nvidia-cuda-toolkit&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all  so it's already available if using Ubuntu *groovy gorilla*.

Comment: @guiverc So I understand in 20.10 this would be available, but not in 20.04 LTS. Is there an easy way for me to "backport" this package to a running 20.04 system, or do I need to upgrade the whole machine to 20.10?

Comment: Have a look at the dependencies of the package (https://packages.ubuntu.com/groovy/nvidia-cuda-toolkit) and you'll see a significant portion of your *focal* system will become *groovy*, and those packages themselves will cause others to also upgrade... and your system will become *groovy*. Your system will EOL when *groovy* EOLs (`ubuntu-security-status` would confirm). You can run packages for other systems via containers (lxc) but I have no idea if that's possible with cuda as I don't know anything about cuda...   Refer to the duplicate link I posted as to why.

Comment: @guiverc Thanks, I see. Since this is a server system, I would rather stick to LTS. So in that case I guess I will install the `deb` directly from Nvidia.

Comment: I don't know cuda, so can't advise directly with it. I personally doubt it would be any difference, and 3rd party packages often mean *release-upgrade* issues in the future, so I personally avoid them if I can, or do my *homework* assessing how their package differs to the official Ubuntu one, in order to predict what impacts you'll likely have; *homework* you'll have to do (my prior comment has details of the Ubuntu package, contrast that with the 3rd party package you're considering.. likewise any differing *deps* etc)